# Ansible: How to copy public key from node to local?

Tags: ansible

How can I copy SSH public keys from each node to ansible server?

In another words make: ssh-copy-id user@ansible_server?

I want to make it automatically using playbook file.

I made some solution:

```
- name: ssh-copy-id
  hosts: builder
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: generate ssh keys on node
      user:
        name: user
        generate_ssh_key: yes
        ssh_key_bits: 2048
        ssh_key_file: .ssh/id_rsa

    - name: get content of public key (node)
      shell: cat "/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
      changed_when: false
      register: public_key

    - name: append public key from node to local authorized_keys
      lineinfile:
        line: "{{ public_key.stdout }}"
        insertafter: EOF
        dest: /local
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Start with [fetch](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/fetch_module.html). But your task is a bit strange, honestly. Why do you need public keys from remote nodes?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: To use rsync from nodes (copy logs to server)

Answer (score 1):

If you generate ssh keys in the same playbook, just capture the result and use it:

```
- name: generate ssh keys on node
  user:
    name: user
    generate_ssh_key: yes
    ssh_key_bits: 2048
    ssh_key_file: .ssh/id_rsa
  register: user_res

- name: append public key from node to local authorized_keys
  lineinfile:
    line: "{{ user_res.ssh_public_key }}"
    insertafter: EOF
    dest: /local
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: But it will not work, because ssh-copy-id also makes file: known_hosts

Comment: You can always add `ssh-keyscan` task.